# Need a query to replace strings(for values and names arranged in row wise) as shown below

Tags: mysql, sql

I need the values of price and weight to replaced in the expression column of formula1 table. COuld anyone help .

I have the below query tried but there is some error.

My query:

```
Select REPLACE((Select Expression from Formula1 
where idnum =1),INPUTNAME,INPUTVALUES) AS TIME FROM Formula1
```

tABLE QUERY'S

```
Create table FORMULA1
(
Expression varchar(MAX),
INPUTVALUES INT,
InputName VARCHAR(256),
)

Insert into Formula1
values('Price+Weight' ,23,'weight')

Insert into Formula1
values('' ,14,'PRICE')
```

Comment: 'Some error'. Gotta love such technically detailed descriptions of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
Select REPLACE(Expression,INPUTNAME,INPUTVALUES) AS TIME FROM Formula1 
where idnum =1
```

(*Also your table is not showing any column by the name of **idnum***)

Answer (score 0):

Your query will work perfectly you just need to take care of case-sensitivity. Replace is tightly couple with case sensitive.

Comment: I'm getting output but it is not the one I require. The output of the query is Price + 23 and 14+ weight. But i actually want it as a single one 14+23. I dont have any ID values in the table too.

Comment: First clear your requirement and design the table accordingly. If you have multiple Price and weight then which price or weight we should select.